# Ignore the observe event when an action runs on an observable

Tags: flutter, mobx

I have an observable x.

```
@observable
double x
```

Now i have an action which mutates the `x`

```
@action
double mutatex(double z){
  x=z;
}
```

Now whenever i call the action, the respective Observer widget gets rebuilt. Is there anyway i can prevent the rebuild of the observer widget upon calling the action. i.e. action method gets called and the mutation happens but the respective observer ignores the action.

Answer (score 1):

That would kinda go against the whole idea of using the Observer, Observable and Action.

You could remove the @action or @observable annotation, but if the UI is rebuilt for a different reason (like screen resize, background and resume, etc) the new result will likely show.

Comment: Thanks MisterJimson. There is a function in mobx called 'untracked'. I tried to use it inside @action. By wrapping the content of the annotated method method in untracked() function i thought i would be able to achieve what i was looking for. So you ```untracked``` can be used for same?